# Add Event to Control added dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using asp.net and c# for webForm. I'm generating a dropDownList dynamically, but I can't execute an event for this control. Below some code:

```
DropDownList nuevoCmb = new DropDownList();
nuevoCmb.ID = "ddl" + num;
nuevoCmb.Items.Add("---Seleccione el Plazo---");
nuevoCmb.Items.Add("Corto Plazo");
nuevoCmb.SelectedIndex = 0;
nuevoCmb.AutoPostBack = true;
nuevoCmb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(nuevoCmb_OnSelectedIndexChanged);
MainPanel.Controls.Add(nuevoCmb);

protected void nuevoCmb_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string temp = "";
}
```

Comment: MainPanel.Controls.Add(cmb); should that be MainPanel.Controls.Add(nuevoCmb);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the follow page: [Creating Dynamic DropDownList Controls in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/creating-dynamic-dropdownlist-controls-in-asp.net.aspx)

This example is fully functional, but only an asp html page, is not working using master page. Any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code that creates the control to every page request, including postbacks.  If the control causes a postback and the code that recreates the control is not called, your event handler will not fire.  .NET will eventually call your event handler once a control with the same ID is added during the page load.

Comment: I'm creating the dynamic controls every times that the page is reloaded in Page_Init Event like suggest Microsoft but, the envent is not firing, yet.

Comment: @user1991662, post the whole method where you call the code  that creates the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

You should add dynamically added controls in or before the page `Init` event.  It also works if you add during page `Load` event.  After the `Load` event, your custom control events bubble up and fire.  So if you're adding controls dynamically, they have to be added on each post back, being loaded before the page `Load` event ends, at the latest.

Comment: Neither, using the Init, neither the PreInit Event the controls are firing the OnselecteIndexChanged Event.